# Chrome Reflections On Flat Surfaces

Tags: mesh, materials, light

I've set up my scene, and both objects have the exact same material applied to them. I understand that the monkey object has lots of curves therefor the light and world scene is bouncing lights and the HRD image to make it seem nice and reflective. But as for the TEXT mesh, although having the same material and light applied to it, it looks flat. would there be a way that the text can also look more realistic like the monkey Suzanne, having more details on its surface?

thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

For orthographic view or camera rays from flat surfaces located at same angle lead to just one pixel of environment texture for both background and reflection.

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion worked well. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's a big deal what kind of hrd image you use. For me this type of image worked nicely, which had a clear horizon in the middle of the image:

[image]
[image]

Oh yeah, and your camera needs to have a fairly low focal length. If you have a long lens like stated in the other answer, you'll have a flat text:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the insight Manu!